any other way to play audio in browser using reactjs other than using DecodeAudioData?
So basically from the server using websocket I am receiving chunks of audio data in the form of ArrayBuffer, so the DecodeAudioData api is not able to decode partial audio into sound, so I was previously using nodejs for the access to the speaker using speaker module and using function like speaker.write(message), now how do I do it in the frontend (Reactjs).
Tried DecodeAudioData api to decode but cannot do it since it cannot play partial audio

What's the format of the data you're receiving.  What exactly do you mean by "partial audio data"?  I assume you're using an AudioContext to decode?  What does this have to do with React?

the format of the data is a ArrayBuffer which contains Array of bytes, so basically I was getting streams of audio data from a web socket connection from a python server. DecodeAudioData() is provided by the AudioContext but it is not able to decode the streams of ArrayBuffer one by one. so basically all of this is done on react ,did you get me @Brad

What's in the ArrayBuffers?  PCM audio samples?  Compressed in some way?  What codecs are in-use?

PCM audio format @Brad

In that case, you don't need to decode... you have the data in the format you need it in to use the Web Audio API ScriptProcessorNode or AudioWorkletNode.  (Just make sure you're setting the right sample rate when setting up the AudioContext.  And, if your samples aren't in floating point, you might need to convert them, but this is just a numeric operation.  No codec work necessary.)  You can also use the new MediaStreamTrackProcessor, if available on your platform.
